# Real time implementation of EtherCAT master with ros_control

Tags: ros, real-time

I want to control a motor using EtherCAT protocol.
1. I used IgH ethercat master to control motor in hard real time (1 kHz).
2. Later I want to integrate this in ros_control with hard real-time control. The developer of ros_control are ensuring that ros_control is real time.
3. If I want to create other application using ros/moveit/ros-android on top of ros_control & ethercat(driver), Can we call the system hard realtime (ros_control + igh (both are hard realtime) and ros (not realtime)) ?

Comment: good luck with your project. do you have any questions?

Comment: @jsotola  can we use for the hard real time application, I have not seen such example ?

Answer (score 1):

You would confuse or mislead people if you called a non-realtime system with realtime subsystems a realtime system.

If your motor control is realtime, just say that. That you have realtime control of the motor position (or whatever feedback parameter is in the realtime domain).

Note that using realtime components incorrectly can result in non-realtime operation and the fact that you claim hard-realtime will make anyone that is evaluating your system look extra carefully to make sure this is true for the operating conditions they care about.